# Is there a way to get the directory of the current (not currently executing) file at runtime?

Tags: perl

I have a .pm file, let's call it A.pm, that I am use-ing in another file B.pl, which lives in a separate directory. Inside A.pm, I would like to reference an external non-perl file that exists in same directory. To avoid hardcoding the path to that external file, I would like to get the directory in which A.pm lives at run time.

I've tried using $FindBin::Bin and File::Spec->rel2abs('.'), but I've learned that those point you to directory of the currently *executing* script, not the current file. $0 gives me the name of the currently executing script as well.

Is there a way to get the directory A.pm lives in aside from hardcoding the path in A.pm?

EDIT: I should also note that I've tried just referencing the external file with path relative to A.pm, but during execution, the code looks for the external file in directory where B.pl lives, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: Note that `File::Spec->rel2abs('.')` is actually a *different* wrong answer: it is the current working directory (at the time that line runs), which is not necessarily the directory that contains either the initial script or the current file.

Comment: how is A.pm installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__FILE__` returns the path that was used to retrieve the file being executed. This means you could use the following:

```
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

dirname(__FILE__)
```

That will fail if a symlink was used to load the file, so one normally wants to resolve symlinks first.

```
use Cwd            qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

dirname(abs_path(__FILE__))
```

This is more important for a script than for a module because the odds of a symlink being used to load a module are quite low.

Warning: These can fail if the CWD changed since the module was loaded.

Comment: Two modules that can wrap this functionality usefully: [Dir::Self](http://metacpan.org/pod/Dir::Self) and my own [lib::relative](http://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative).

Comment: @Grinnz, Both of those have the same bug as my first snippet.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if I'd call that a bug. If the user loads a script or module via a symlink, how is the author to know that they should search in the destination, not where the symlink is? I can think of use cases where you would want the latter. Anyway as you noted, in practice it's a rare problem.

Comment: @Grinnz, If you installed two files into the same directory (or in a relative one), the approach used by Dir::Self and lib::relative to find the neighbouring file won't always find the file. I would definitely call not being able to find the file you want to find -- or worse, finding the wrong file -- a bug. Not just a bug, but potentially a major security vulnerability! (That's why `.` is no longer in `@INC`.)

Comment: I am considering replacing the incantation to `File::Spec->catdir(File::Basename::dirname(Cwd::abs_path __FILE__), 'path/to/lib')` (with checking for if `__FILE__` exists for oneliners, as abs_path is not portable for nonexistent files). Can you think of any cases where this approach would fail? I appreciate your insight.

Comment: @Grinnz, `__FILE__` and `$0` are `-e` for one-liners. /// Using `catdir` (which should be used as `catdir(..., 'path', 'to', 'lib')` to be useful) is overkill (except possibly to support VMS?) /// It could fail if the CWD is changed earlier in the program, as I already mentioned. It could also fail if the script is deleted and such, but there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Right, it contains caveats already about the chdir risk and passing file paths in the format expected by the OS - and the catdir is overkill for Unix/Windows but a small overkill for maximum portability.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already `use`'d or `require`'d a module, the location of the file resides in `%INC`.

```
$ perl -MJSON -E 'say $INC{"JSON.pm"}'
/opt/share/perl5/site_perl/5.16/JSON.pm
```

Comment: That doesn't get a *directory*. For that, you'd need `dirname(abs_path($INC{"Foo/Bar.pm"}))`, but aformentioned `dirname(abs_path(__FILE__))` is simpler.

Comment: Also there is no guarantee that where you loaded some other module from is the same place the current module is being loaded from, even if both are in sitelib.

Comment: @Grinnz, JSON was just an example. You'd use the name of the relevant module.